# Random black & white pixels in Racket

Tags: racket

I'm doing an [exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1S1J.png) from picturing-programs.

I'm also not sure if the exercise wants me to just produce a white rectangle or a black rectangle or a rectangle with randomized black and white pixels.

The solution is not coming straight to me and I might be overlooking something simple. Any tips to solve are appreciated.

My approach so far has been thinking of a way to make a black or white pixel appear in one spot randomly and I'm not sure on how to do that yet either.

I'll add the code for that also.

This code is not fully functional either because I was trying different things, so excuse the randomness of certain functions or expressions.

I've been able to create random colors everywhere, but not explicitly black & white pixels.

```
(define (safe-2.55xy x y)
  ; x a number
  ; y a number
  (min 255 (real->int  (abs(- (random 255)255)))))

"Examples of random-bw-picture:"

(define white (color 255 255 255 255))
(define black (color 0 0 0 255))

(define (random-pixels-picture width height)
  (build3-image width height safe-2.55xy  safe-2.55xy  safe-2.55xy))

(define (black-pixel-function x y)
  (min 255 (real->int   0 )))

(define (build-black-pixel x y )
  (make-color 0 0 0))

(define (build-white-pixel x y )
  (make-color 255 255 255))

(build-image 100 100 build-black-pixel)
(build-image 100 100 build-white-pixel)

(define (random-bw-picture width height)
  (cond [(number? width) (random-pixels-picture width height)]
        [(number? height) (random-pixels-picture width height)]
        [else (random-pixels-picture width height)]))
```

Comment: What's the point of a `cond` where every clause does the same thing? (And what do you expect to happen if any of `width` and `height` *isn't* a number?)

Comment: There are some quite weird things there, like `(min 255 (real->int   0 ))` (which is 0, and not a colour) and `(min 255 (real->int  (abs(- (random 255)255))))` (which even without the `min` is a number between 1 and 255; `(random 1 256)`).

Comment: The entirety of all this code is a bit random, no pun intended. I just couldn't think of a way to do it, so I just started writing random code. I was using build3-image because that's what the author was saying to use on a later exercise in the book. I was also experimenting between the two. Nothing was coming to me naturally, so I started just writing confused code. That's why my cond was just the same condition.

Comment: So defining a color black and white is a possible approach? I'm guessing there's others as well.

Comment: As for (min 255 (real->int   0 ))) I was just reusing code so I didn't delete all of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed overlooking simple things (and overcomplicating).

`build-image` is like `build3-image`, but takes only one function that produces a complete colour.

Everything you need except that is a function that produces either black or white at random, and then you can

```
(define (random-bw-picture width height)
  (build-image width height black-or-white))
```

Now, given the definitions you already have,

```
(define white (color 255 255 255 255))
(define black (color 0 0 0 255))
```

you can pick a number from 0 and 1, and choose a colour:

```
(define (black-or-white x y)
  (if (= (random 2) 0)
      white
      black))
```

Answer (score -1):

So instead of the if I used a conditional

```
(define white (color 255 255 255 255))
(define black (color 0 0 0 255))

(define (black-or-white x y)
  (cond [(= (random 2) 0) black]
        [else white]))

(define (random-bw-picture width height)
  (build-image width height black-or-white))
```